# How do I load an Elliptic Curve PEM encoded Private Key?

Tags: java, cryptography, bouncycastle, private-key, elliptic-curve

I've generated an elliptic curve private/public key pair using OpenSSL. The private and public keys are PEM encoded. I've figured out how to load the public key thanks to [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40439081) However, I can't figure out how to load the private key, as the above message just ends up with an InvalidKeySpecException: key spec not recognized.

I then found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23369629), but it also ends up with an "encoded key spec not recognised". How can I load my private key?

```
private PrivateKey loadPrivateKey(String location) {
    try {
        // Strip the guarding strings
        byte[] bytes = stripGuardLines(location);

        return KeyFactory.getInstance("ECDH").generatePrivate(new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(bytes));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        LoggerFactory.getLogger("Nectar").error("Failed to find Private KEY: " + location);
        System.exit(1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LoggerFactory.getLogger("Nectar").error("IOException while loading Private Key!");
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }

    return null;
}

private byte[] stripGuardLines(String location) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(location));

    String line;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
        if(line.contains("EC PRIVATE KEY")) { //Check if guard line
            continue;
        }
        sb.append(line);
    }
    // Guard lines stripped, now decode base64

    return Base64.getDecoder().decode(sb.toString());
}
```

Here is the private key file:

```
-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
MIGkAgEBBDD2MFRv6BpJU6/zDI2yBfVbe0oeU1nFAoYMedDGtcdwHyWNJSeiYRBA
pVNzMxPSBLWgBwYFK4EEACKhZANiAAQBttEp/qUGnDlmL+o6KZnVs+RoBnEBEGho
PxSUu1Xfj77QQqfuqHOCRzWXseQA1aZB/h6VQEiFovugtG1G3HaMxxrqLLxb10g2
BMaRcAfZyeqc3O0Ui8XXb1esn0gOrCU=
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Comment: I *think* you've just got the most minimal encoding instead of a PKCS#8 compliant structure. Create your own PKCS#8 from Java and compare with the online ASN.1 decoder (encode to base 64 first).

Comment: Yep, just confirmed, this is the X9.62 structure that is *inside* the PKCS#8 structure.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22963581/reading-elliptic-curve-private-key-from-file-with-bouncycastle/41947163 now improved

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 You can directly [link to your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41947163/589259) by hitting the share button below it. Or close questions as duplicate (invoking dual gold badge powers, beware).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes: I didn't link my answer specifically because it is not the only good one (now) and probably not the best. Personally I use 'openssl to pkcs8 then JCE' or in cases with a cert 'openssl to pkcs12'. I answered about BC only because that point in the Q hadn't been addressed. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code outputs only the key itself. It is missing the algorithm specifiers required for PKCS#8 encoded private keys. Fortunately the key itself always has the same size when encoded (it doesn't use any ASN.1 integers, which may have different sizes as far as I can see).

That means that you can simply concatenate the header from another key:

```
// static header you can put in front
byte[] header = Hex.decode("30 81bf 020100 301006072a8648ce3d020106052b81040022 0481a7");
// your key from the PEM above
byte[] fromPEM = Base64.decode("MIGkAgEBBDD2MFRv6BpJU6/zDI2yBfVbe0oeU1nFAoYMedDGtcdwHyWNJSeiYRBApVNzMxPSBLWgBwYFK4EEACKhZANiAAQBttEp/qUGnDlmL+o6KZnVs+RoBnEBEGhoPxSUu1Xfj77QQqfuqHOCRzWXseQA1aZB/h6VQEiFovugtG1G3HaMxxrqLLxb10g2BMaRcAfZyeqc3O0Ui8XXb1esn0gOrCU=");
byte[] bytes = Arrays.concatenate(header, fromPEM);
PrivateKey ecPrivate = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC").generatePrivate(new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(bytes));
```

this code is both Bouncy Castle compatible as compatible with the default implementation in the Java JRE from Oracle.

---

Note that you might as well use Oracle compatible code to create your key pair as well:

```
KeyPairGenerator kpGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC");
kpGen.initialize(new ECGenParameterSpec("secp384r1"));
KeyPair ecKP = kpGen.generateKeyPair();
```

Comment: Kind of obvious, but since the header contains length encodings and an OID of the named curve, this will only work for secp384r1 (or P-384, same thing) curves.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Probably better that way, would vote up answer. My option is more of a hack around the issue (didn't have time to muck around with `openssl` at work :P).

Comment: (ninja) Or let OpenSSL convert the PEM: `openssl pkey <raw >pkcs8` (or especially in 0.9.8 or lower `openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -nocrypt <raw >pkcs8`) then strip and base64-decode that. Or convert to DER at the same time with `openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -nocrypt -outform der <raw.pem >pkcs8.der` and use that directly -- but _not_ `pkey -outform der` which outputs legacy/raw!

Comment: Thanks, I ended up converting the .PEM from the "old format" to the "new format" using

    ```openssl pkey -in [old] -out [new]```