# JAVA 11 - elliptic curve private key - Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException : version mismatch: (supported: 00, parsed: 01

Tags: java, elliptic-curve, ecdsa

Small question regarding getting an elliptic curve private key with Java please.

I run this command in my terminal:

`openssl ecparam -name secp256k1 -genkey -noout -out ec-secp256k1-dummy-priv-key.pem`

This commands is working fine, generating the file fine, I can even `cat` the file, which I can see:

```
-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
MHQCAQEEIDHE7OA9hgIYW427NieIsXz/qAipMVhqVUIwVcEIWwuAoAcGBSuBBAAK
oUQDQgAEcMu2KlVzJLKQ9XfoWvF0jZ+JwbPeUekHqTYVTFK9ISoKLgBN9abxIxyc
JumqIshcc74GUVtm/sJJoiPJNdEPEQ==
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----
```

(please note here it is written BEGIN **EC** PRIVATE KEY and not BEGIN PRIVATE KEY)

Now, I get ride of the `\n` and spaces, etc, basically to have the "inside" of the key, configured as a one line string.

```
String s = "MHQCAQEEIDHE7OA9hgIYW427NieIsXz/qAipMVhqVUIwVcEIWwuAoAcGBSuBBAAKoUQDQgAEcMu2KlVzJLKQ9XfoWvF0jZ+JwbPeUekHqTYVTFK9ISoKLgBN9abxIxycJumqIshcc74GUVtm/sJJoiPJNdEPEQ==";
```

(please let me know if this step is wrong)

What I tried: I then use this piece of code to get the private key

```
String s = "MHQCAQEEIDHE7OA9hgIYW427NieIsXz/qAipMVhqVUIwVcEIWwuAoAcGBSuBBAAKoUQDQgAEcMu2KlVzJLKQ9XfoWvF0jZ+JwbPeUekHqTYVTFK9ISoKLgBN9abxIxycJumqIshcc74GUVtm/sJJoiPJNdEPEQ==";

        byte[] keyData = Base64.getDecoder().decode(s);
        EncodedKeySpec privKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keyData);
        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC");
        PrivateKey privKey = kf.generatePrivate(privKeySpec);
```

Unfortunately, it is yielding this error

```
SEVERE: null
java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException : version mismatch: (supported:     00, parsed:     01

Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException : version mismatch: (supported:     00, parsed:     01
    at java.base/sun.security.pkcs.PKCS8Key.decode(PKCS8Key.java:350)
    at java.base/sun.security.pkcs.PKCS8Key.decode(PKCS8Key.java:355)
```

I am having a bit of a hard time understanding the issue, and how to fix this.

If possible, I would like to avoid falling back to bouncy castle, avoid changing the way the key is being generated, avoid having to convert the key to yet again another format.

May I ask what did I do wrong, and what is the correct way to fix this issue please?

Thank you

Comment: While I agree converting to pkcs8 as answered is the best way, you _can_ read this format in plain Java by adding a fixed-per-curve prefix to the decoded (binary) SEC1 format to make it PKCS8 format, along the lines shown in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41927859/how-do-i-load-an-elliptic-curve-pem-encoded-private-key but that case is secp384r1 and you'd need a different actual prefix for secp256k1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I can read from the [PKCS8EncodedKeySpec Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/security/spec/PKCS8EncodedKeySpec.html), the input to the constructor must be a PKCS8 encoded private key. However, the [openssl ecparam command](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Command_Line_Elliptic_Curve_Operations) apparently does not generate the key in PKCS8 format. If I understand the documentation correctly, you would need to convert the private key to PKCS8 like so:

```
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -nocrypt -in ec-secp256k1-dummy-priv-key.pem -out p8file.pem
```

Then you can strip the newlines and BEGIN/END tags and feed that into PKCS8EncodedKeySpec.

Comment: A quick test with the above conversion passed.

Comment: Indeed, learned something new about the command today. This is the correct answer. Upvote + accept, thanks a lot and good day

Comment: Nit: to dePEMify remove BEGIN/END lines and linebreaks _and decode base64_ (which OP did). An alternative conversion is `openssl pkey -in legacy.pem -out pkcs8.pem`, or you can do the generation with `openssl genpkey` instead of `openssl ecparam -genkey`.

Comment: Learned something new again, thanks a lot!

Comment: Perfect - saved lot of time, thanks.