# How to create private key from pkcs12 in java

Tags: java, rsa, bouncycastle, pkcs#12

I need to create PrivateKey from privateKeyContent which is in pkcs12 format. Below code doesn't work for it.

```
   KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
   PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpecPKCS8 = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode(privateKeyContent));
   PrivateKey privateRsaKey = kf.generatePrivate(keySpecPKCS8);
```

It gives me this error.

```
java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException : version mismatch: (supported:     00, parsed:     03
    at java.base/sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.engineGeneratePrivate(RSAKeyFactory.java:251)
    at java.base/java.security.KeyFactory.generatePrivate(KeyFactory.java:390)
```

How to do it correctly in java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PKCS12 format is a container that may have multiple keys and certificates. PKCS8 file always has one key. In your code sample, you apply **PKCS8**`EncodedKeySpec` to **PKCS12** input, this is obviously not going to work because of this. You need to switch from Key-level APIs to KeyStore APIs.

You can read PKCS12 container like this:

```
InputStream keyFile = ...; //input stream to key file
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
ks.load(keyFile, "<filePassword>".toCharArray());
```

and extract a specific key from the loaded storage:

```
String keyAlias = "1"; // all existing aliases can be obtained by ks.aliases()
Key key = ks.getKey(keyAlias, "<keyPassword>".toCharArray());
```

This is how you can read a key from [this specific demo .p12 file](https://itv.mit-xperts.com/clientssl/issue/dload/index.php?id=1693731657):

```
InputStream keyFile = ...; // load file as an IS
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
ks.load(keyFile, null);
Key key = ks.getKey("1", "test".toCharArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem like your key is an RSA Key.

You probably need to convert your key first before using it. For example:

```bash
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -nocrypt -in key.pem -out new-key.pem
```

You can refer to [JAVA 11 - elliptic curve private key - Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException : version mismatch: (supported: 00, parsed: 01](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70194425/java-11-elliptic-curve-private-key-caused-by-java-security-invalidkeyexcept) for more details